# Visual force page as pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I a m trying to get a visualforce page as a pdf page, i am using some css code also, but on pdf page no css class is added to fields, but inline css  i can add to fields,  someone tell me how to add css classes with fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can add CSS via a static resource.  There is more in the developer force article [Creating Professional PDF Documents with CSS and Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce).

Use the `apex:stylesheet` tag along with the `URLFOR` function to access the static resource. For example, with a static resource of `advancedpdfresource` that has a css file in it called `qstyles.css` do:

`<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.advancedpdfresource, 'qstyles.css')}"/>`.

Then in your code you can use the class attribute if you are using normal HTML elements or the styleClass attribute if you are using supported standard components (e.g., `apex:outputPanel`, etc.). For example:

`<apex:outputText value="{!myControllerProperty}" styleClass="myCssClass" />`

If you are having trouble, one helpful way to troubleshoot can be to render the PDF as html instead and inspect it with a browser tool such as the Chrome developer console to see what's going on with the styles.